# A "human cue tip"?

Tags: meaning, expressions, metaphors

I am watching the excellent documentary "Nobelity" by Turk Pipkin:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nobelity
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turk_Pipkin

4 minutes into the movie, there is a bit that I don't understand.  Here is the transcript:

> Do you ever get the feeling that everything really is broken?
> That no matter who you are or where you come from,
> the world is somehow divided into us and them.
> Here I am, Turk Pipkin, shooting my film "Nobelity" at a Shiah festival in Kolkata.
> I was warned not to say that I am an American
> But it's not like they couldn't tell.
> **My camera man said I looked like a human cue tip.**

The picture shows Turk Pipkin, a very tall caucasian man with pale skin and white hair, holding his camera and surrounded by short Indians with dark skin and dark hair.

I understand that the cameraman wanted to say that he stood out in the crowd, but I don't understand the expression "human cue tip". At least that's what it sounds like: I am not sure I transcribed properly.

Can you explain this expression and the metaphor?

[Edit:]
Oops, the movie is actually "One Peace at a time", another of Pipkin's movies:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Peace_at_a_Time
I got confused because he refers to his earlier movie in the quote.

The answers make sense. I didn't know the brand "Q-tip". What's the word for brand names that are used as common nouns in every day language?

Comment: *What's the word for brand names that are used as common nouns in every day language?* Answer: *[generic(ized) trademark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genericized_trademark)* or *[proprietary eponym](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genericized_trademark)*.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I believe you are thinking of Q-tip. The passage means the guy was tall and very white by comparison with his companions.

[image]

You can read all about it:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cotton_swab

Comment: I believe the comparison of Turk to a cotton swab in this instance has as much or more to do with his hair than  with his height or skin color. It is very white and, well, [cottony](http://www.flickr.com/photos/48110867@N04/4425275717/)!

Comment: @Calli: Ah, thanks for the link. Didn't even know how Turk looked like until now. Definitely, his hair plays a big part in this metaphor. Great point!

Answer (score 2):

*Cue tip* is a misspelling of *Q-tip*, a popular brand of cotton swabs/buds in the United States. Here, *Q-tip* is as a metaphor for Pipkin's height† and whiteness, both of which stand out in sharp contrast to the physical features of the Indians surrounding him.

---

<sub>*Credit for the "height" aspect of this metaphor goes to [Robusto's answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/18244/a-human-cue-tip/18245#18245). Included it here in the spirit of completeness.*</sub>